# Get data from GDAX web socket feed

Tags: c#, websocket

I want to get data from this wss://ws-feed.gdax.com

I don't know anything about websocket. I am reading some tutorials and it uses terms like websocket server, TCP, etc which I have no idea about. Can anyone please advice how should I proceed, how to write a c# code to get data from the above.

This is the document which I reading to fetch real time data - https://docs.gdax.com/#websocket-feed

Started by creating a window app. Read here that the WebSocketSharp library can be used to connect WebSockets so installed it and so far written this code:

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com"))
        {
            ws.Connect();
             string json = "{\"type\": \"subscribe\",    \"product_ids\": [\"BTC-USD\"]}";
            ws.Send(json); //gives error -Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClientWebSocket socket = new ClientWebSocket();
Task task = socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com"), CancellationToken.None);
task.Wait();
Thread readThread = new Thread(
    delegate(object obj)
    {
        byte[] recBytes = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            ArraySegment<byte> t = new ArraySegment<byte>(recBytes);
            Task<WebSocketReceiveResult> receiveAsync = socket.ReceiveAsync(t, CancellationToken.None);
            receiveAsync.Wait();
            string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recBytes);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("jsonString = {0}", jsonString);
            recBytes = new byte[1024];
        }

    });
readThread.Start();
string json = "{\"product_ids\":[\"btc-usd\"],\"type\":\"subscribe\"}";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
ArraySegment<byte> subscriptionMessageBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes);
socket.SendAsync(subscriptionMessageBuffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you do is in the right direction. Just check websocket state before you read the message.

The below example is from https://github.com/sefbkn/gdax.netcore, with little modification

```
var webSocketClient = new ClientWebSocket();
var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();

await webSocketClient.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com"), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (webSocketClient.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    var requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
        type = "subscribe",
        product_ids = new[]{"ETH-EUR"},
        channels = new[]{"ticker"}
    });

    var requestBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);
    var subscribeRequest = new ArraySegment<byte>(requestBytes);
    var sendCancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
    await webSocketClient.SendAsync(subscribeRequest, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, sendCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    while (webSocketClient.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        var receiveCancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
        using(var stream = new MemoryStream(1024))
        {
            var receiveBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024*8]);
            WebSocketReceiveResult webSocketReceiveResult;
            do
            {
                webSocketReceiveResult = await webSocketClient.ReceiveAsync(receiveBuffer, receiveCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await stream.WriteAsync(receiveBuffer.Array, receiveBuffer.Offset, receiveBuffer.Count);
            } while(!webSocketReceiveResult.EndOfMessage);

            var message = stream.ToArray().Where(b => b != 0).ToArray();
            messageReceived(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, 0, message.Length));
        }
    }
}
```